# Independence of two products of random variables with common factor

Tags: probability, random-variables, independence

Suppose I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, each of which is the product of some other random variables. They have at least one common factor and one different factor.
For example, letting $A, B, C \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ i.i.d.:

$X := AB, \quad Y := AC$

When simulating numerically, I find that $\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$, which could indicate independence of the variables.
I am a bit confused about this due to the common term and am not sure if my intuition about dependence and independence is right. Is there a simple way I can prove (in)dependence in this case or a good way to reason about it?

I have seen [Independence of two products of random variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/344724/independence-of-two-products-of-random-variables), but decided to ask anyways because I would like to gain an intuition about the simulation result.

Comment: Independence implies $\mathbb EXY=\mathbb EX\mathbb EY$. But the converse is not true in general.

Comment: @drhab I've changed the phrasing to reflect this so others reading the questions won't be confused by it. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Independence and vanishing covariance are the same only for the normal distribution. As mentioned by others, this is not a property that holds in general.

Comment: @PeterKeller "only" is correct iff you restrict to continuous distributions. If $X,Y$ are Bernoulli then it works too.

Comment: @drhab the Bernoulli-idea is cool. I think it should work with other two-point distributions as well. That may help when reasoning about symmetric random variables in the product where the sign could be seen as a two-point (-1, 1). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

$X$ and $Y$ are not independent because $E(X^{2}Y^{2})=EA^{4}EB^{2}EC^{2}=EA^{4} \neq 1$ and $(EX^{2})(EY^{2})=EA^{2}EB^{2}EA^{2}EC^{2}=1$.